# C - Function read(file,buffer,bytes to read) breaking a string

Tags: c, pthreads, lseek

I'm trying to read a file with 1024 lines with 9 times the same letter in each line and returning if it finds a line that doesn't match this terms.

**The file is as follow but with 1024 lines:**

```
eeeeeeeee
eeeeeeeee
eeeeeeeee
```

**Code:**

```
fd = open(fileName, O_RDONLY);
lseek(fd,0,SEEK_SET);


if(flock(fd, LOCK_SH) == -1)
        perror("error on file lock");

if(fd != 0){

    read(fd, lineFromFile, (sizeof(char)*10));
    arguments->charRead = lineFromFile[0];

    for(i=0; i < 1024; i++){        
        var = read(fd, toReadFromFile, (sizeof(char)*10));  
        if(strncmp(toReadFromFile,lineFromFile,10) != 0 || var < 10){           

            arguments->result = -1;
            printf("%s \n\n",toReadFromFile);
            printf("%s \n",lineFromFile);
            printf("i %d var %d  \n",i,var);                
            free(toReadFromFile);
            free(lineFromFile);
            return ;
        }                       
    }
}
```

**Output:**

```
> eeeee
eeee 

eeeee
eeee 
i 954 var 6
```

I have 5 different files with different letters and every single one gives this output in that specific line (954) and the line is correct with the letter writen 9 times with a \n in the end.

Any ideas why this could be happening?  If i don't use the lseek it works fine but i need the lseek to divide the file in several parts to be tested by different threads. I put the 0 index in the lseek for simplification to show you guys.

Thanks.

Comment: If you are trying to read a text file line by line it would be better to let library functions do the work for you by using `fgets()` or `fscanf()`. Instead of using `fseek()` each thread could simply discard any lines prior to those it is interested in. Another route could be to read in the whole 10k file (it's not huge and you know its size) into static memory available to all the threads and let them all examine the same copy.

Comment: Could it be that one of your other threads is doing an `lseek` on your file as you are reading from it?  You should move the `lseek` down below where you lock the file.  That way you can only `lseek` once you have the lock.

Comment: The problem is, since I already have other program using threads that read the whole file, this new program needs to share the same file to be faster testing it and my teacher says it's mandatory to use lseek() and read(). And i don't understand how can it work for most of the lines and just fail in that specific line. Makes no sense.

Comment: Are you sharing the same `fd` across all threads?  Or are you calling `open` once per thread?

Comment: I moved the lseek to after the lock and it does the same. I'm using an `open` on each thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are looking for `"eeeee\neeee"` instead of `"eeeeeeeee\n"`.  Which means your file should should start like this:

```
eeeee
eeeeeeeee
eeeeeeeee
```

and end like this:

```
eeeeeeeee
eeee
```

If your file ends like this:

```
eeeeeeeee
eeeeeeeee
```

Then when you get to the last line, it will fail because you will only read `"eeeee\n"` instead of `"eeeee\neeee"`.

Given the new information in your comment, I believe the problem is that you should not be seeking to the middle of lines (in this case 342 and 684).  You should seek to an even multiple of the expected string (like 340 and 680).  Also, line 954 is not where the problem happened.  It should be line 954 + X, where X is the line you seeked to.

Comment: but it is failing in line 954 and last line is 1024. If i use 3 threads with the following lseeks: lseek(fd,0,SEEk_SET) lseek(fd,342,SEEk_SET) lseek(fd,684,SEEk_SET) - the first 2 are successfull and the last one fails at line 954. 

If it started with eeeee shouldn't it fail for 1st 2 threads? Or only fail in line 1024?

Comment: Interesting.  Why are you seeking to 342 and 684?  Shouldn't you be seeking to offsets that are divisible by 10?  Also, you shouldn't be looking at line 954 in your file.  You should be looking at line X + 954, where X is the line you seeked to.  In your case, you seeked to the middle of line 68, so the problem happened on line 68 + 954 = 1022, or 1023 if the first line is line 1.

Comment: you are right :D I changed the for and saved the return from lseek like this:
`newIndex =lseek(fd,arguments->startLineIndex*10,SEEK_SET);` `for(i=newIndex/10; i< arguments->finishLineIndex; i++)` Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Whatever other problems your program may have, it certainly has this: the `read()` function is not guaranteed to read the full number of bytes requested.  It will read at least one unless it encounters an error or the end of the file, and under many circumstances it does read the full number of bytes requested, but even when there are enough bytes remaining before the end of the file, `read()` may read fewer bytes than requested.

The comments urging you to use a higher-level function instead are well considered, but if you are for some reason obligated to use `read()` then you must watch for cases where fewer bytes are read than requested, and handle them by reading additional bytes into the unused tail end of the buffer.  Possibly multiple times.

In function form, that might look like this:

```
int read_all(int fd, char buf[], int num_to_read) {
    int total_read = 0;
    int n_read = 0;

    while (total_read < num_to_read) {
        n_read = read(fd, buf + total_read, num_to_read - total_read);
        if (n_read > 0) {
            total_read += n_read;
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }

    return (n_read < 0) ? n_read : total_read;
}
```

Comment: already solved but thanks anyway. I really needed to use lseek for this one.

Comment: You may indeed have needed to use `lseek()`, but that does not mean that you do not *also* need to do what I described.  Even if your program so far happens to have given you the expected results without, it is not safe to rely on it always to do so.